# Negative Numbers in C# TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have gone through the questions here and have found the answer for making a textbox accept only numeric values with one decimal and negative sign at the beginning.

```
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.' && e.KeyChar != '-')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    // only allow one decimal point
    if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    if (e.KeyChar == '-' && (sender as TextBox).Text.Length > 0)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

However I do have one problem. Suppose the user typed a number:

123455789764

And then he realizes that the number is negative. He goes back to the beginning and tried to type in the negative sign, only to find that it's not working. Is there a way to address this problem instead of getting the user to delete the number that he typed, add the negative number and retype the number again?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't evaluate every single character stroke, but just when your form is submitted?

Comment: Just use a regular expression to check if the textbox only contains numbers when the form is submitted. This Expression is for numbers only: `^[0-9]+$`. But since RegExes aren't my specialty, I cannot tell you what you need to add to allow a negative sign... :(

Comment: Your solution doesn't help versus pasting. If you copy a text you can still paste it, and thus circumvent your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^-?\d+[.]?\d*$");
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) return;
        if (!reg.IsMatch(textBox1.Text.Insert(textBox1.SelectionStart, e.KeyChar.ToString()) + "1")) e.Handled = true;
    }
```

For the suggestion of keyboardP, I add this code to fully prevent non-numeric value, I think you should try `TextBox.ShortcutsEnabled = false;` because I don't think user needs any kind of copying and pasting numeric data.

```
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"^-?\d+[.]?\d*$");
    bool textChangedByKey;
    string lastText;
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) return;
        if (!reg.IsMatch(textBox1.Text.Insert(textBox1.SelectionStart, e.KeyChar.ToString()) + "1"))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
        textChangedByKey = true;
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (!textChangedByKey)
        {
            if (!reg.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
            {
                textBox1.Text = lastText;
                return;
            }                
        }
        else textChangedByKey = false;
        lastText = textBox1.Text;
    }
```

I've tried using `Undo()` method with some resetting `SelectedText`, however it's a little bad, even the way above doesn't bring a good visual effect (you can see the text changing and restoring to the valid value when try pasting text into the numeric textbox).

Comment: @keyboardP OK I updated it to allow decimal numbers, however the dash is unable to be input multiple times as you said. I've tested it.

Comment: +1 - Not sure why it wasn't working. I created a new project (tested on an existing sandbox Winform) and it works fine. You'll need to prevent pasting of text so within the `TextChanged` event you need to add `if (!reg.IsMatch(textBox1.Text)) textBox1.Clear();`

Comment: @keyboardP thank you, I think the OP should notice that, the code is just demo :)

Comment: That's fine, just posting in case OP skips it. Best solution to this prob IMHO :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Evaluate characters only when some "OK" or "Submit" button is clicked, not on every keystroke
2. Use a regular expression to check the *entire* text for validity, not just the typed character **OR**
3. Try to parse the text into a `long` using `Int64.TryParse` and evaluate the `bool` result of the call.
4. Having read all the above: **Why not simply use a `NumericUpDown` control?**

Comment: 1. The value is used by other controls so i can't wait for OK or Submit. Plus it is irritating to see a message box popping up saying that the data is invalid :P        
2. Thanks Just used King Kong's answer for REGEX.        
3. I have no idea how to do this.       
4. Donno doesn't seem user friendly for this situation. I think users will be more happy with a text box than a NumericUpDown

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the length of the string (and discarding "-" when it's non-zero), you could check the cursor position and discard "-" when the cursor is not a the beginning or when there is already a "-" at the beginning.

But doing the whole check later during submission instead of swallowing keystrokes might be better UX.

Comment: Wont this actually slow the program, since it checks each time the cursor is moved?

Comment: @Kris134: The check is really fast and will not slow down the program, no. And you are already doing checks everytime a key is pressed, anyway. Plus, you only need to check the cursor position when "-" is pressed, not everytime the cursor is moved.

Answer (score 0):

I think that relying on textbox events is a better approach to your problem. In any case, you can continue using your methodology and complement it with events to account for the heading "-" issue. This code deletes any dashes from the textbox unless being in the first position:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Contains("-") && (textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1) != "-" || textBox1.Text.Split('-').Length > 2))
            {
                bool headingDash = false;
                if (textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1) == "-")
                {
                    headingDash = true;
                }
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("-", "");
                if (headingDash)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "-" + textBox1.Text;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I dont think that will help my case. The code you've given runs the code IF the first char is '-'. I want the system to only allow the user to add the '-' as the first char.

Comment: I did misunderstand your point (not too good day :)) but my code can easily be updated to what you want. I have changed it: now you have exactly what you want.

Comment: PS: and you can do equivalent things to account for all what you want without relying at all on pressed keys.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (although you may consider some modification depending on how you want to handle decimal separators (as number format is dependant on CurrentCulture settings)

This accepts only numbers, the length and further formatting of input (e.g. only one digit allowed before decimal separator) is not addressed, although I think it can be modiffied to do that.

```
public enum NumericTextBoxType { TDecimal = 1, TByte, TShort, TInt, TLong }

    public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
    {
        #region ARRAYS

        private static readonly Keys[] separators = 
        {
        Keys.Decimal,
        Keys.Oemcomma,
        Keys.OemPeriod
        };

        private static readonly Keys[] allowed =
        {
        Keys.D1,
        Keys.D2,
        Keys.D3,
        Keys.D4,
        Keys.D5,
        Keys.D6,
        Keys.D7,
        Keys.D8,
        Keys.D9,
        Keys.D0,
        Keys.NumPad0,
        Keys.NumPad1,
        Keys.NumPad2,
        Keys.NumPad3,
        Keys.NumPad4,
        Keys.NumPad5,
        Keys.NumPad6,
        Keys.NumPad7,
        Keys.NumPad8,
        Keys.NumPad9,
        Keys.Decimal,
        Keys.Oemcomma,
        Keys.OemPeriod,
        Keys.OemMinus,
        Keys.Subtract,
        Keys.Back,
        Keys.Delete,
        Keys.Tab,
        Keys.Enter,
        Keys.Up,
        Keys.Down,
        Keys.Left,
        Keys.Right
        };

        private static readonly Keys[] intallowed =
        {
        Keys.D1,
        Keys.D2,
        Keys.D3,
        Keys.D4,
        Keys.D5,
        Keys.D6,
        Keys.D7,
        Keys.D8,
        Keys.D9,
        Keys.D0,
        Keys.NumPad0,
        Keys.NumPad1,
        Keys.NumPad2,
        Keys.NumPad3,
        Keys.NumPad4,
        Keys.NumPad5,
        Keys.NumPad6,
        Keys.NumPad7,
        Keys.NumPad8,
        Keys.NumPad9,
        Keys.OemMinus,
        Keys.Subtract,
        Keys.Back,
        Keys.Delete,
        Keys.Tab,
        Keys.Enter,
        Keys.Up,
        Keys.Down,
        Keys.Left,
        Keys.Right
        };

        #endregion ARRAYS

        #region PROPERTY NumericTextBoxType

        private NumericTextBoxType _NumericTextBoxType = NumericTextBoxType.TDecimal;

        public NumericTextBoxType NumericTextBoxType
        {
            get
            {
                return
                _NumericTextBoxType;
            }
            set
            {
                _NumericTextBoxType = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion PROPERTY NumericTextBoxType

        #region PROPERTY AllowMinus

        public bool AllowMinus { get; set; }

        #endregion

        string prvText = "";
        int prevSelStart = 0;

        public NumericTextBox()
            : base()
        {
            this.NumericTextBoxType = NumericTextBoxType.TDecimal;
            this.AllowMinus = true;
        }

        #region EVENT METHOD OnKeyDown

        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);

            if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
            {
                prvText = this.Text;
                prevSelStart = this.SelectionStart;
                return;
            }

            // ignore not allowed
            if (NumericTextBoxType != NumericTextBoxType.TDecimal)
            {
                if (!intallowed.Contains(e.KeyCode)) e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!allowed.Contains(e.KeyCode)) e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                else if (separators.Contains(e.KeyCode))
                {
                    NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
                    string decimalSeparator = numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator;

                    int selLength = this.SelectionLength;
                    int selStart = this.SelectionStart;

                    if (!this.Text.Remove(selStart, selLength).Contains(decimalSeparator))
                    {
                        this.Text = this.Text
                        .Remove(selStart, selLength)
                        .Insert(this.SelectionStart, decimalSeparator);
                        this.SelectionStart = selStart + decimalSeparator.Length;
                    }
                    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                }
            }

            // ignore minus if not first or not allowed
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemMinus || e.KeyCode == Keys.Subtract)
            {
                if (!this.AllowMinus) e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                else if (NumericTextBoxType == NumericTextBoxType.TByte) e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                else if (this.SelectionStart > 0) e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }

            prvText = this.Text;
            prevSelStart = this.SelectionStart;
        }

        #endregion EVENT METHOD OnKeyDown

        #region METHOD OnTextChanged

        protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnTextChanged(e);

            // don't allow incorrect paste operations
            if (Regex.IsMatch(this.Text, (!AllowMinus ? "[-" : "[") + @"^\d.,]") ||
            Regex.Matches(this.Text, @"[.,]").Count > 1)
            {
                this.Text = prvText;
                this.SelectionStart = prevSelStart;
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is tooo much coding in this. It could slow down the program

Comment: Well, it probably may be further optimized, but I don't think it's that slow. It doesn't blink, it deals with the "paste" issue and is reusable :)